# MongoDB database is missing, how to backup .ns file

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

I made a backup of the /data/db folder where there is a .ns and .0 files.
But when I put back the /data/db folder on my new server, the databases are missing.

How can I restore the database from these files ?

Here is the files in /data/db folder

[image: Missing databases but the files are here]

But when browsing databases, the `utravel` database doesn't appears :

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551